# How to measure data size being transfered internally with socket.io

Tags: node.js, file-upload, websocket, socket.io

We know that socket.io doesn't transfer binary. When we send binary (binary string) data over socket.io, it escapesit and send it to the server. I need how much of size does this way add to the actual size of the binary string and compare between it and base64 encoded string size.

What I'm doing is uploading files using socket.io and I have seen many base64 examples which increases around 33% of the file size. I'm looking for a safe way to upload the files which is supported by all browsers supported by socket.io itself without that big size increase. I know that Websockets transfer binary but the problem is with IE8 IE9. Therefore, I'm looking into binary string transfer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the solution on an Microsoft.NET based platform you can have a look at [XSockets.NET](http://xsockets.net/api), it supports binary (RFC6455) 
WebSockets messages.  If the client don't support binary you could use base64 encoded messages.